# Lock Screen Orientation with window.matchMedia

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen, screen-orientation

I have a screen that by using dev tools and toggling the device toolbar
I was able to develop a mobile version of that screen.

I have written a small on chance lister that allows me to determine which orientation the screen is in, whether that is portrait or landscape.

If the user is in landscape mode I want to "lock" it in portrait mode. I am not using an android or apple device, just a simple web page.

Does anyone have familiarity with this sort of functionality...

```
    let portrait = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

    portrait.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        if (e.matches) {
            //Portrait
            console.log('Portrait');

        } else {
            // Landscape, need to lock in portrait. 
            console.log('Landscape');

        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot lock the orientation for a device. You can add a "pop up" which asks the user to rotate the device?

Comment: Check out this resource: https://usefulangle.com/post/105/javascript-change-screen-orientation